# How to make an activity above the MainActivity.java?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

My current `MainActivity` is a navigation drawer.
I want to make another activity on top of the navigation drawer.
Lets make that activity `StartActivity`.

On `StartActivity` there is a start button.
What i want to do is make the StartActivity opens up first when the app runs.
And when the user presses the START button on the StartActivity, it will direct him/her to the navigation drawer.

is this possible?

Comment: This is very confusing. Are you not using fragments?

Comment: I don't understand the question. :(

Comment: @codeMagic: I guess OP wants to create a welcome screen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the StartActivity.
2. somewhere call "startActivity(intentforMainactivity);
3. go to the manifest and move

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```

   from the

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="sehtestapp.MainActivity"
   ```

into

```
    <activity
        android:name="sehtestapp.StartActivity"
```

Your Application will then start the StartActivity first

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Create another Activity, that you'll call StartActivity
- 2) Set up a layout that you'll use in your StartActivity with a
  button in it.
- 3)Create the onClickListener to launch a new Intent when clicked.
  Make it launch the MainActivity.

4) Change your AndroidManifest as follow :

```
<activity
    android:name="XXX.StartActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="XXX.MainActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="XXX.StartActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the Launcher activity and send intent having a boolean bundled in it when START button is pressed, in MainActivity fetch the intent, read that boolean value and open the drawer programmatically.